# d3 image with higher resolution

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I successfully fill rectangles with images. However, the resolution is really low.

I am wondering if there is anything I can do to increase my image's resolution?

I don't know if it's a problem of size because even when i increased my rectangle's size, the resolution is still pretty bad.

My source code:

```
function initRectElements(svg, data) {
    imgUrl = "image/star/5.png";
    d3.select(svg).append("defs")
            .append("pattern")
            .attr("id", "rating")
            .attr("width", rectwidth)
            .attr("height", rectheight)
            .append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", imgUrl)

    var sel = d3.select(svg)
            .selectAll('rect.token')
            .data(data);

    sel.enter().append('rect')
            .classed('token', true);

    sel.exit().remove();

    d3.select(svg).selectAll('rect.token')
            .attr('x', function (d){return d
                    .x})
            .attr('y', function (d){return d
                    .y})
            .attr("width", rectwidth)
            .attr("height", rectheight)
            .attr('fill', "url(#rating)")
}
```

The output is something like this:

[image]

Comment: How big is the source png?

Comment: I resized it to 100*30 to match the size of my rectangle object created by d3